# Trying to iterate through the following output python

Tags: python-3.x

I have an output in the following format
my intention is to only display the value of number which is inc123

````
{
success: true,
transaction_id: "x",
data: {
incident_ticket: {
transform_map: "test",
number: "inc123",
state: "some value",
category: "Application"
}
}
}```
````

Comment: do you mean `print(the_dict_you_mention[data][incident_ticket][number])`

Comment: yep ultimately i want only to display the value of number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this output belongs to a variable named `infos`, you can use:

```
infos['data']['incident_ticket']['number']
```

Thats because the number is inside incident_ticket, which is inside data.

Comment: I tried this 
infos={
success: true,
transaction_id: "x",
data: {
incident_ticket: {
transform_map: "test",
number: "inc123",
state: "some value",
category: "Application"
}
}
}

y =infos['data']['incident_ticket']['number']
print(y)
********
but i got 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iterate.py", line 4, in <module>
    success: true,
NameError: name 'success' is not defined

Comment: writing success the way you did makes python understand that success is a variable, try putting succes and all the other informations in quotes

Comment: change success to `"success"`

Comment: Hi gustavo, thank you, but this is an output of a post method not sure if there is any other way of doing it